# Reference request for Arnold Diffusion

Tags: dynamical-systems, classical-mechanics, perturbation-theory, celestial-mechanics

I'm trying to understand Arnold diffusion from its original paper: Instability of dynamical systems with several degrees of freedom by V.I. Arnold.

Is there any book where this topic is detailed or largely discussed?

Comment: Adding more details would be a good idea. What do you mean by Arnold diffusion?Do you have any examples?

Comment: @MrYouMath: It's a rather well-known phenomenon in dynamical systems: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arnold_diffusion

Comment: You might want to look into the book "Mathematical aspects of classical and celestical mechanics" by Arnold, Kozlov, Neishtadt and references therein.

Answer (score 1):

After some more investigation, I found a very good qualitative explanation of the phenomenon at chapter 5 of : Celestial Encounters: the origins of Chaos and Stabilty, F. Diacu and P. Holmes.